Springboot Quartz (Clustered mode)
I am trying to run a Quartz Scheduler application in clustered mode.
In a non-clustered setup, I am able to read/write DB without any issue. However, in a clustered setup, I encounter errors related to datasource. I read that JobStoreTX is an indicator of Cluster setup but it seems to be causing issue. Please help!
Specification:
Springboot Gradle / MSSQL / using org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(QuartzConfiguration.class);

    @Primary
    @Bean()
    @QuartzDataSource
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource quartzDataSource() {

        HikariDataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        return dataSource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void validateQuartzDataSource() {
        LOG.info("Quartz DataSource bean should have been created");
    }
}

Note: For both setups, "Quartz DataSource bean should have been created" is logged.
org.quartz.jobstore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

LocalDataSourceJobStore - JobStoreCMT initialized. QuartzScheduler -
Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with
instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'   Scheduler class:
'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.   NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.   Number of jobs executed: 0   Using thread
pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.   Using
job-store
'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' -
which supports persistence. and is not clustered. StdSchedulerFactory

Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.


spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

JobStoreTX initialized. QuartzScheduler:294 - Scheduler meta-data:
Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId
'NON_CLUSTERED'   Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' -
running locally.   NOT STARTED.   Currently in standby mode.   Number
of jobs executed: 0   Using thread pool
'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.   Using
job-store 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' - which supports
persistence. and is not clustered. StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz
scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided
properties instance.
JobStoreTX - Database connection shutdown unsuccessful. java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named
'quartzDataSource'

